# Посчитать долю отфильтрованных строк в общей массе строк

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных, обработка-данных, статистика

Есть файл с данными. Необходимо отфильтровать данные, отвечающие определенному условию (содержание определенного слова в определенном столбце) и посчитать долю отфильтрованных данных в общей массе данных (то есть посчитать долю отфильтрованного кол-ва строк в общем кол-ве строк).

Для того, чтобы отфильтровать данные я воспользовался следующими командами:

```
import pandas as pd

frame=pd.read_csv('file_name', header=0, sep='\t') 
frame.столбец[frame.столбец.str.contains('необходимое_слово')]
```

Я получил строки.

Вопрос: с помощью каких команд можно посчитать долю отфильтрованных строк в общей массе строк?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
frame['столбец'].str.contains('необходимое_слово').mean()
```

---

Пример:

```
In [98]: df
Out[98]:
     name
0    John
1   Willy
2     Max
3   Oscar
4  Yorick
5   Denis

In [99]: df[df['name'].str.contains('o')]
Out[99]:
     name
0    John
4  Yorick

In [100]: df['name'].str.contains('o').mean()
Out[100]: 0.3333333333333333
```

---

Как это работает:

```
In [101]: df['name'].str.contains('o')
Out[101]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: name, dtype: bool
```

Внутреннее представление `True` в Python - это `1`:

```
In [105]: 1 == True
Out[105]: True

In [106]: 0 == False
Out[106]: True

In [110]: True + True
Out[110]: 2
```

соотвественно мы можем суммировать `boolean` столбец:

```
In [102]: df['name'].str.contains('o').sum()
Out[102]: 2
```

доля отфильтрованных строк в общей массе строк:

```
In [103]: df['name'].str.contains('o').sum() / len(df)
Out[103]: 0.3333333333333333
```

или одной командой - взять среднее по столбцу:

```
In [109]: df['name'].str.contains('o').mean()
Out[109]: 0.3333333333333333
```